# Android ndk camera2 api

Tags: c++, android-ndk, android-camera2

can somebody provide a short example on how to snap camera frames with NDK, C++ Camera 2 api?

I couldn't find any meaningful resources out there as it's sort of brand new API, however would be thankful for any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a good example of using camera2 from within C++ here: https://github.com/justinjoy/native-camera2

It's easy to follow and I got it running in a few minutes.

Comment: I have backported this solution to API 23: https://github.com/alexcohn/native-camera2

Answer (score 1):

There aren't sample apps available yet, but you can take a look at the basic compliance test for the camera2 NDK API:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/camera/libctscamera2jni/native-camera-jni.cpp